# How do you ADD and DROP columns in a single ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, syntax, alter-table

I tried the following but I got a syntax error

```
ALTER TABLE Grades ( 
DROP COLUMN (Student_FamilyName, Student_Name),
ADD Student_id INT );
```

Is it possible to perform a `DROP` and an `ADD` in the same `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Comment: You can't do drop and create with one alter statement, separate it

Comment: You switch to PostgreSQL (cough), which supports [multiple changes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/currrent/static/sql-altertable.html) as an extension to standard SQL syntax.  (But even though I use PostgreSQL a lot, I *usually* write SQL that avoids extensions.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 31):

If you look at the [ALTER TABLE SYTAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

you'll see this

```
ALTER TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name 
{ 
    ALTER COLUMN column_name 
    { 
        [ type_schema_name. ] type_name [ ( { precision [ , scale ] 
            | max | xml_schema_collection } ) ] 
        [ COLLATE collation_name ] 
        [ NULL | NOT NULL ] [ SPARSE ]

    | {ADD | DROP } 
        { ROWGUIDCOL | PERSISTED | NOT FOR REPLICATION | SPARSE }
    } 
        | [ WITH { CHECK | NOCHECK } ]

    | ADD 
    { 
        <column_definition>
      | <computed_column_definition>
      | <table_constraint> 
      | <column_set_definition> 
    } [ ,...n ]

    | DROP 
     {
         [ CONSTRAINT ] 
         { 
              constraint_name 
              [ WITH 
               ( <drop_clustered_constraint_option> [ ,...n ] ) 
              ] 
          } [ ,...n ]
          | COLUMN 
          {
              column_name 
          } [ ,...n ]
     } [ ,...n ]
```

This can be reduced to

`ALTER TABLE { ALTER COLUMN column_name | ADD | DROP }`

According to [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx) the **| (vertical bar)**

> Separates syntax items enclosed in brackets or braces. You can use only one of the items.

So you can't Alter, Drop or Add in a single statement. You also have the parens and comma that won't work. So you'll need

```
ALTER TABLE Grades DROP COLUMN (Student_FamilyName, Student_Name);
ALTER TABLE Grades ADD  Student_id INT;
```

If you need them to be an atomic action you just need to wrap in transaction

Comment: "_If you need them to be an atomic action you just need to wrap in transaction_" - Doesn't Oracle DDL cause implicit commits?

Comment: Or as in T-SQL:
  ALTER TABLE Grades DROP COLUMN Student_FamilyName, COLUMN Student_Name;

Answer (score 8):

In case your database is MySQL, you can do it this way:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Grades
    DROP COLUMN Student_FamilyName, 
    DROP COLUMN Student_Name,
    ADD Student_id INT;
```

Works in **MySQL 5.5.5**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one:

```
ALTER TABLE Grades
  DROP Student_FamilyName, 
  DROP Student_Name,
  ADD Student_id INT;
```

and you can use before/after like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Grades
  DROP Student_FamilyName, 
  DROP Student_Name,
  ADD Student_id INT AFTER id;
```